# This piece of code works on document ready without even clicking the button. Why is that?

Tags: jquery, function, button, onclick, click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div> Old Content </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(hidefunction());
});

function hidefunction(){

// Hide all divs on the page
$("div").hide();

}
</script>

<div> New Content. If you click on me, I will disappear.This jquery code doesn't work if we takeout document.ready code from function. The Function "hidefunction" works by itself. Without clicking the button the "div" hides.  </div>
<button> Hide all div</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: call the `hidefunction()` as a callback: http://jsfiddle.net/M6mUg/

Comment: `typeof(hidefunction) === 'function'` & ∴ the behavior is as expected

Answer (score 3):

You are calling hidefunction instead of passing the reference to the function. try this:

```
$("button").click(hidefunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
$("button").click(hidefunction());
```

You are calling the `hidefunction`, if you want to pass a function via parameter, dont add `()`

```
$("button").click(hidefunction);
```